# How to work with rack using ruby for storing image on cloudinary with gem carrierwave

Tags: ruby, rack, ruby-grape

I am using rack framework with active record and there is no rails ,   so when i upload an image to cloudinary using carrierwave gem i am getting the following error.

> Unexpected error while processing request: uninitialized constant
>   Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage::Rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off of [this](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave/storage.rb) ,you can't use carrierwave gem without rails. You should be able to do something like:

you can use [meta-programming in ruby](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval).

Just override the class of Carrierwave and create a storage.rb file :

```
Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage.class_eval do
 /// Your code here...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

That was a bug in cloudinary gem, now this has been solved by Cloudinary team.

Please refer to this [#Issue-154](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/154)

Hope it helps.